# How to stop animated list widget refreshing all the widgets at once?

Tags: flutter

The following `list widget` has a `text` in the middle in each `list item`. I want the each text to be unique, so I'm feeding the text when I build the each item then adds to the list, but when I add new `list Item` or select an item by clicking on it to remove one single item, all the list items gets refreshed and previous `list item's` middle text also gets updated to new text I feed. How to prevent all the textboxes update to the last text I enter, I want it to retain it's text?

```
import 'package:app3/widgets/Profile-Card/tool-set-button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app3/GlobalVariables/GlobalVariables.dart';

class AnimatedListWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? presetText;

  const AnimatedListWidget({
    Key? key,
    this.presetText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AnimatedListWidget> createState() => _AnimatedListWidgetState();
}

class _AnimatedListWidgetState extends State<AnimatedListWidget> {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _listKey = GlobalKey<AnimatedListState>();
  late ListModel<int> _list;
  int? _selectedItem;
  late int _nextItem;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _list = ListModel<int>(
      listKey: _listKey,
      initialItems: <int>[0, 1, 2],
      removedItemBuilder: _buildRemovedItem,
    );
    _nextItem = 3;
  }

  String messageText = '';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
          Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter, //list alignment
              child: Container(
                  width: 200,
                  child: FittedBox(
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      child: SizedBox(
                        width: 100,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: SingleChildScrollView(
                            child: Container(
                              height: 300,
                              child: AnimatedList(
                                shrinkWrap: true,
                                key: _listKey,
                                initialItemCount: _list.length,
                                itemBuilder: _buildItem,
                              ),
                              //),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )))),
          Container(
            width: 300,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.black,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8,
                      left: 5,
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 219,
                            child: ToolSetButton(
                                svgPicPathChecked: '',
                                svgPicPathUnchecked: '',
                                buttonType: myButtonTypeList.TextButton,
                                text: 'Add',
                                width: 200,
                                height: 60,
                                functionReceiverforButtonandSVG: () {
                                  addPresetToList();
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8,
                      left: 5,
                    ),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                      child: Container(
                        width: 100,
                        child: FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          child: SizedBox(
                            width: 219,
                            child: ToolSetButton(
                                svgPicPathChecked: '',
                                svgPicPathUnchecked: '',
                                buttonType: myButtonTypeList.TextButton,
                                text: 'Remove',
                                width: 200,
                                height: 60,
                                functionReceiverforButtonandSVG: () {
                                  removePresetFromList();
                                }),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]));
  }

  Widget _buildItem(
      BuildContext context, int index, Animation<double> animation) {
    return PresetObject(
      animation: animation,
      item: _list[index],
      selected: _selectedItem == _list[index],
      presetText: widget.presetText,
      onTap: () {
        _selectedItem = _selectedItem == _list[index] ? null : _list[index];
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildRemovedItem(
      int item, BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
    return PresetObject(
      animation: animation,
      item: item,
    );
  }

  void addPresetToList() {
    final int index = 0;
    //_selectedItem == null ? _list.length : _list.indexOf(_selectedItem!);
    _list.insert(index, _nextItem++);
  }

  // Remove the selected item from the list model.
  void removePresetFromList() {
    if (_selectedItem != null) {
      _list.removeAt(_list.indexOf(_selectedItem!));
      setState(() {
        _selectedItem = null;
      });
    }
  }
}

typedef RemovedItemBuilder<T> = Widget Function(
    T item, BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation);

class ListModel<E> {
  ListModel({
    required this.listKey,
    required this.removedItemBuilder,
    Iterable<E>? initialItems,
  }) : _items = List<E>.from(initialItems ?? <E>[]);

  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> listKey;
  final RemovedItemBuilder<E> removedItemBuilder;
  final List<E> _items;

  AnimatedListState? get _animatedList => listKey.currentState;

  void insert(int index, E item) {
    _items.insert(index, item);
    _animatedList!.insertItem(index);
  }

  E removeAt(int index) {
    final E removedItem = _items.removeAt(index);
    if (removedItem != null) {
      _animatedList!.removeItem(
        index,
        (BuildContext context, Animation<double> animation) {
          return removedItemBuilder(removedItem, context, animation);
        },
      );
    }
    return removedItem;
  }

  int get length => _items.length;

  E operator [](int index) => _items[index];

  int indexOf(E item) => _items.indexOf(item);
}

class PresetObject extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? presetText;
  const PresetObject(
      {Key? key,
      this.onTap,
      this.selected = false,
      required this.animation,
      required this.item,
      this.presetText})
      : assert(item >= 0),
        super(key: key);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final VoidCallback? onTap;
  final int item;
  final bool selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TextStyle textStyle = defualtParahTextStyle;
    if (selected) {
      //if selected change colour of text etc
      textStyle = textStyle.copyWith(color: Colors.lightGreenAccent[400]);
    }
    return Column(children: [
      Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
          child: SizeTransition(
              sizeFactor: animation,
              child: GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                onTap: onTap,
                child: Container(
                    width: postInner0CardWidth,
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors
                                .primaries[item % Colors.primaries.length],
                            width: 1)),
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        child: RichText(
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            text:
                                TextSpan(style: textStyle, children: <TextSpan>[
                              TextSpan(text: variableAddNewPreSetTextMessage)
                            ])))),
              )))
    ]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keys or ovveride rebuild method if you are using statefull widget other wise use Object key and pass your tile object in that and in your model class you must override hashcode or extends with equatable

So by passing key when flutter rebuild widget if previous key data is remain same then it will not rebuild that tile again

or visit keys in flutter docs